# how to make an android library project obfuscate inside eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm developing an android library. as i say i want to make it obfuscate. I have searched a lot but i just reached the following points:

1- Eclipse doesn't run proguard on Android Project

2- The only way to make a library obfuscate is that to use it in another application and run proguard on that application and then decompile the application and fetch the library, but for god's sake it's a bad solution.

is anyone has any idea to solve my problem?

i have already changed my `project.properties` to this

```
target=android-21
android.library=true
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

but of course it's not working! :))

Comment: Have you tried this? http://androidtechlaunch.blogspot.com.es/2013/07/android-library-project-obfuscation.html

Comment: @GoRoS: yes, but it doesn't work either

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: Realistically, if you are serious about building a library to distribute to other developers (such that you want to obfuscate the library internals, not just the final APK), then you should probably not be using Eclipse for your production builds, but rather only for development ones.  Invest the time in setting up a real (ant, gradle, whatever you like) build system with automatic versioning which pulls from your version control repository, and runs proguard with whatever settings you like.

Comment: This has already been answered here anyway, see john.k.doe's or pulp's answers at the linked duplicate (rather than the making an apk and extracting it one).  If you are really into clicking buttons in Eclipse rather than using the command line or setting up a build server, you can add one of their answers as a custom post build step.